# PHP script is not being executed by cron

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, cron

I have a very weird issue that I'm gonna pull my hair off..

I have php script ran by cron. When I manually run

```
php /var/www/html/mypath/mycron.php > output.html
```

it works fine, the script takes about 3 mins, and I can get the output I need.

But when it's called by cron like this

```
0 1 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mypath/mycron.php > output.html
```

it does not work, nothing's written to output!

I've tried add `-f`, doesn't work; I've check php max_execution_time, it's more than enough;
I've check the cron log, it says it ran, but I got nothing in output;
I've checked the permission, the crontab is under the user I manually run, and all the directories in `mypath` under html are owned by that user, and have `rwx` for owner, shouldn't have had any permission issue; I've try to create new cron under the same directory just for testing, and it worked...

It's driving me crazy, any idea why this is happening?? Thanks!

Comment: can you post the result of ```which php```

Comment: @mazedlx it is the `/usr/bin/php`. when I copy the script from crontab and run it works..